# Java library for managing Apple Push Notifications

Tags: java, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I found out that there are 2 open source projects I can use:
javapns (http://code.google.com/p/javapns/)
and java-apns (http://github.com/notnoop/java-apns)

Both of them are pretty good, but do not handle error responses. When you compose a payload in  enhanced format, you can include an identifier with the payload and send it to Apple Push Notification Server. You can read on the socket and receive the status of the response(matched by the identifier sent in the notification), if there was an error.

But, none of the java libraries handle this case. Is there a good reason why the libraries are not reading the socket for a response ?

Also, let me know what other java libraries you have used.

Greatly appreciate you help.
thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should look into [java-apns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns/) again. As of 0.1.5, it now supports the enhanced payload format. It also has a separate monitoring thread that listens for errors sent when using the enhanced format. Unfortunately, out of the box, you can't set the identifier for each notification so it's difficult to match up the error response with the notification that Apple didn't like. (I raised an [issue](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns/issues#issue/26) about this on GitHub.)

Answer (score 1):

JavaPNS was recently updated to 2.0, and it includes full support for the enhanced notification format.  You can set the identifier manually if you'd like, but the library will by default generate its own identifiers and match them automatically to error-response packets.  Essentially, you no longer need to worry about identifiers, as error-responses are automatically matched to sent messages by the library, and can be checked easily with a simple method call: yourPushedNotification.isSuccessful().

Answer (score 0):

Another open source lib is Pushy http://relayrides.github.io/pushy/

Answer (score 0):

This one is very good i have used it

https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns

I have also tried javaapns

https://code.google.com/p/javapns/

but some how it was not worked for me. It was giving me success = true on sending notification but my device was not able to receive it.